# Removing strings from C source code

Tags: c, string, code-formatting, utility, reformatting

Can anyone point me to a program that strips off strings from C source code? Example

```
#include <stdio.h>
static const char *place = "world";
char * multiline_str = "one \
two \
three\n";
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        printf("Hello %s\n", place);
        printf("The previous line says \"Hello %s\"\n", place);
        return 0;
}
```

becomes

```
#include <stdio.h>
static const char *place = ;
char * multiline_str = ;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        printf(, place);
        printf(, place);
        return 0;
}
```

What I am looking for is a program very much like [stripcmt](http://www.bdc.cx/software/stripcmt/)
only that I want to strip strings and not comments.

The reason that I am looking for an already developed program and not just some handy regular expression is
because when you start considering all corner cases (quotes within strings, multi-line strings etc)
things typically start to be (much) more complex than it first appears. And
there are limits on what REs can achieve, I suspect it is not possible for this task.
If you do think you have an *extremely* robust regular expression feel free to submit, but please no naive `sed 's/"[^"]*"//g'` like suggestions.

(No need for special handling of (possibly un-ended) strings within comments, those will be removed first)

Support for multi-line strings with embedded newlines is not important (not legal C), but strings spanning multiple lines ending with \ at the end must be supported.

This is almost the same as the [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914913/regular-expression-for-stripping-strings-from-source-code) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676296/how-to-tokenize-parse-string-literals-from-javascript-source-code) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965667/regex-to-parse-c-source-code-to-find-all-strings), but I found no reference to any tools.

Comment: Purely as a matter of interest, why do you need such a tool? In other words, what are you going to do with the tool's output?

Comment: It is for token searching. For instance "in what files are functions x, y and z called". By pre-processing, removing comments and strings I will get an accurate result. Currently the strings are generating noise.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use  a code analysis tool that understands C? There are a lot of them.

Comment: I want to use find + xargs together with a check script (with no setup required), where this check script strips comments and strings first before doing the real work (which as an example could be to check that if a file calls printf, <stdio.h> should be included).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the [source code to StripCmt](http://www.bdc.cx/download/stripcmt/stripcmt-0.1.2.tar.gz) (.tar.gz - 5kB). It's trivially small, and shouldn't be too difficult to adapt to striping strings instead (it's [released under the GPL](http://www.bdc.cx/software/stripcmt/readme.txt)).

You might also want to investigate the official lexical language rules for C strings. I found [this](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/classes/cs453/fall08/DOCS/cminusminusspec.html) very quickly, but it might not be definitive. It defines a string as:

```
stringcon ::= "{ch}", where ch denotes any printable ASCII character (as specified by isprint()) other than " (double quotes) and the newline character.
```

Comment: I had not thought of checking the source of stripcmt. It was simple to modify.

Answer (score 5):

All of the tokens in C (and most other programming languages) are "regular". That is, they can be matched by a regular expression.

A regular expression for C strings:

```
"([^"\\\n]|\\(['"?\\abfnrtv]|[0-7]{1,3}|x[0-9a-fA-F]+))*"
```

The regex isn't too hard to understand. Basically a string literal is a pair of double quotes surrounding a bunch of:

- non-special (non-quote/backslash/newline) characters
- escapes, which start with a backslash and then consist of one of:

  - a simple escape character
  - 1 to 3 octal digits
  - x and 1 or more hex digits

This is based on sections 6.1.4 and 6.1.3.4 of the C89/C90 spec. If anything else crept in in C99, this won't catch that, but that shouldn't be hard to fix.

Here's a python script to filter a C source file removing string literals:

```
import re, sys
regex = re.compile(r'''"([^"\\\n]|\\(['"?\\abfnrtv]|[0-7]{1,3}|x[0-9a-fA-F]+))*"''')
for line in sys.stdin:
  print regex.sub('', line.rstrip('\n'))
```

**EDIT:**

It occurred to me after I posted the above that while it is true that all C tokens are regular, by not tokenizing everything we've got an opportunity for trouble. In particular, if a double quote shows up in what should be another token we can be lead down the garden path. You mentioned that comments have already been stripped, so the only other thing we really need to worry about are character literals (though the approach Im going to use can be easily extended to handle comments as well). Here's a more robust script that handles character literals:

```
import re, sys
str_re = r'''"([^"\\\n]|\\(['"?\\abfnrtv]|[0-7]{1,3}|x[0-9a-fA-F]+))*"'''
chr_re = r"""'([^'\\\n]|\\(['"?\\abfnrtv]|[0-7]{1,3}|x[0-9a-fA-F]+))'"""

regex = re.compile('|'.join([str_re, chr_re]))

def repl(m):
  m = m.group(0)
  if m.startswith("'"):
    return m
  else:
    return ''
for line in sys.stdin:
  print regex.sub(repl, line.rstrip('\n'))
```

Essentially we're finding string and character literal token, and then leaving char literals alone but stripping out string literals. The char literal regex is very similar to the string literal one.

Comment: In this case I think it would be better: ([^"\\\n]|\\.)*

Comment: Your regular expression fails to handle
<<char * str = "one \<eol>two \<eol>three\n";>> where the <eol> indicates that there is a newline. This is what I meant by corner cases :)

Comment: Using \ to join lines is part of preprocessing, and I was ignoring that. (eg: what if the code is <<char *a = MACRO_THAT_EXPANDS_TO_STRING_LITERAL;>> -- what do you want to do then?) If all you care about is the line-joinging, you can add \n in the abfnrtv character class, and replace the for-loop with sys.stdout.write(regex.sub(repl, sys.stdin.read()). You'll also need to tweak chr_re if you're worried about line-joining inside of char literals.

Comment: Another option, depending on what you want this for, would be to run all of the code through the preprocessor first.

Answer (score 0):

In ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
f=open(ARGV[0],"r")
s=f.read
puts(s.gsub(/"(\\(.|\n)|[^\\"\n])*"/,""))
f.close
```

prints to the standard output

Answer (score 0):

In Python using pyparsing:

```
from pyparsing import dblQuotedString

source = open(filename).read()
dblQuotedString.setParseAction(lambda : "")
print dblQuotedString.transformString(source)
```

Also prints to stdout.